# Sbt run test in dependency

Tags: scala, testing, sbt

I packaged the tests files and published them to local ivy via `test:publishLocal`, using this setting:

```
.settings(publishArtifact in (Test, packageBin) := true)
```

Then, in another project, I can reference this library with `libraryDependecies +=`. Now, I want to use these classes. But the `test` command only looks into sources, like `src/test/scala`. How to instruct it to look into the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could write a test class that `extends` from the test class in the dependency that you want to run, and just inherits its members (methods and fields) with no members of its own. I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

By `inspect`ing `test` recursively, I got to this:

```
progfun-actorbintree:->inspect test:test::defined-tests
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.TestDefinition]
[info] Description:
[info]  Provides the list of defined tests.
```

Executing it I get:

```
progfun-actorbintree:->show test:test::defined-tests
[info] List(Test actorbintree.BinaryTreeSuite : subclass(false, org.scalatest.Suite))
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 11/12/2013 15:50:30
```

Which is the sole test class in this project.

So I think that's what you need to modify to get the tests from the library. I recommend doing some inspecting yourself to get further details, such as what is a `TestDefinition` -- one of the things associated with tests is the framework, which might be another thing you'll need to specify.